# How do I turn off the unlimited whitespace in IntelliJ editor?

Tags: intellij-idea, editor, text-cursor

How do I remove the ability to move the cursor after the end of line in IntelliJ?

Comment: It's funny - I want exactly the opposite for Eclipse, to enable virtual space. But I see it's currently an unresolved bug (21000).

Comment: Go here to vote for "unlimited whitespace" to be turned off as the default: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6478

Comment: Guys, could you provide more information on why that virtual space is inconvenient for you?

Comment: Just personal preference. I think the wording could be a little clearer, but I also think it should stay the same default behavior. It makes IntelliJ have a unique feel.

Comment: @denis.zhdanov It is contrary to all editors I've used so far. I often find that I have to look around to find where the cursor is.

Comment: @denis.zhdanov I want to be able to press right-arrow and get to the beginning of the next line from the end of the current, or click arbitrarily to the right of a line and have the cursor end up exactly on the end of the line.  I seldom want to put the cursor an arbitrary distance beyond the end of existing text and have the editor insert a bunch of whitespace for me when I start typing.  I understand some people might prefer being able to do that, but for me I'd rather have it work as I'm used to every other text editor working. It's great that it's configurable, everyone's happy.

Comment: Intellj 13 has changed the default for this to be off.

Comment: Good! I use WebStorm (where the default is apparently off) and IntelliJ (where it's on) and it's driving me nuts going back and forth. (Not to mention years of habits built up from using Eclipse.)

Comment: Apparently, this can also happen in 'Column' select mode which IntelliJ will report in the status bar at the bottom-right. I was able to turn it off using the (Mac) hotkey: Cmd + Shift + 8

Comment: @denis.zhdanov Also the fact that you have to spend time positioning the cursor so that you don't have five spaces before that new `else` clause...

Answer (score 790, accepted):

File menu -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Virtual Space and uncheck 'Allow placement of caret after end of line' . You may also uncheck the other options in the Virtual Space panel.

Comment: As a side effect, this lets me use the right arrow key to move the cursor from the end of a line to the beginning of the next line. Exactly what I wanted.

Comment: it's strange they have a default that everybody would want to turn off.

Comment: All my virtual space options are turned off already, but I still have this... Any other solutions?

Comment: In IntelliJ 11.1 (OS X), its Preferences > Editor > "Allow placement of caret at end of line"

Comment: I like that "intellij disable click anywhere" is the first search suggestion when you type "intellij disable" in google.

Comment: AHH. I can breathe a sigh of relief now; this "feature" was about to make me lose my mind! Thank you!

Comment: @BrianGordon Not for me it isn't - it was "disable spell check". Which, to be fair, I was also about to google, right after I'd found this. It is kind of weird that this was on by default, but I am impressed at the sheer number of options available. It might well be that I *won't* have to install any addons to get a usable UI for IntelliJ, which I can't say the same for VS2010 (no middle mouse scroll, no way to turn off ctrl+middle mouse = zoom in. Who would want to zoom in on code often enough to make it a shortcut??)

Comment: In Intellij 12 Ubuntu, it's found under File > Settings > Editor

Comment: At last! This was driving me insane. The exact instructions were out of of date for Intellij 13 on Mac OS X, but one of the comments above pointed me in the right direction. Namely, disable this checkbox: Preferences > Editor > Allow placement of caret at end of line.

Comment: Did this break with the last (15.0.1) update? I've never noticed this before, the mentioned setting is off, but the cursor still places after the end of line.

Comment: There's a bug in my version. It started doing this with it off. I had to toggle the setting to get it to stop being annoying.

Answer (score 239):

If the other answers don't seem to be working, you might have `Column Selection Mode` enabled. On my Mac it's mapped to <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>. It's located under the **Edit** menu. That menu item will show a little checkmark when the mode is enabled.

Comment: For me this option was the issue. I used the shortcut `Shift`+`Cmd`+`A`, typed in `Column Selection Mode` and turned it off.

Comment: Sweet, I think I accidentally turned this on while creating a scratch file. My hotkeys were `Shift`+`Alt`+`Insert`. For anyone one else looking for it, just open the settings and search for `Column Selection Mode` and it'll bring up its hotkey. As another note, I am on Intellij 15 using Centos 7.

Comment: This helped! Must have hit it by accident. Any other suggested solution didn't change anything.

Comment: This worked for me too, but I had to manually uncheck it from the menu with the mouse -- the shortcut is correct but didn't seem to work :/

Answer (score 21):

To get the expected behavior where **indentations** are respected when you click on a line :

In *Preferences > Editor > Virtual Space*

*Check* :

> Allow placement of caret inside tabs.

*Uncheck* :

> Allow placement of caret after end of line.

This was really annoying to me and makes very little sense as a default behavior to me.

Comment: This is a weird setting. I use spaces instead of tabs, but it works as expected. The setting should probably read `Allow placement of caret inside indents`.

Answer (score 19):

Note that for Intellij IDEA 11 for mac, settings are placed under the IntelliJ IDEA menu and called preferences. (Maybe some sort of mac default ?)

Comment: You can always searching "caret" to find the setting you want.

Answer (score 4):

What Matt_Bro said (first answer), but if you've already got the box unchecked in preferences, try re-checking it (I checked all the virtual space boxes) and restarting. Then uncheck and hit apply--at this point unlimited space was disabled for me.

Comment: i also had to close and re-open the file i was editing.

Answer (score 4):

#### IntelliJ IDEA 2016

By default, it's **turned off** (unchecked).

If it is turned on, you can use one of the following **2 approaches**:

1. **File** > **Settings...** (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) > **Editor** > **General** > Virtual Space section > uncheck **Allow placement of caret after end of line**

   [image: File > Settings]

   [image: Editor General Allow placement]
2. **Help** > **Find Action...** (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) > type "**Virtual Space: Allow end**" > <kbd>Enter</kbd> or left click (to switch between On and Off) > <kbd>Esc</kbd>

   [image: Help > Find Action]

   [image: Allow Caret On Off]