# IntelliJ IDEA - Help in preference

Tags: intellij-idea, cursor, settings

I am trying to convert myself to IJ IDEA for now a couple of days. 
When I started to use it, I noticed something that bugs me incredibly:
being able to write where ever you click in the code area.

Is it possible to deactivate that??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I turn off the unlimited whitespace in IntelliJ editor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593214/how-do-i-turn-off-the-unlimited-whitespace-in-intellij-editor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings->Editor->Virtual Space: *Allow placement of caret after end of line*